# In which of the LCR circuit the charge will decay faster?

Tags: capacitor, resistors, circuit-analysis, inductor, passive-networks

Our instructor gave this problem.

> Cc << C. At time t = 0, the capacitor C has charge Q. In which circuit 
>   the charge Q will decay faster.

[image: Question_Image]

Its answer is Charge Q decays faster in (A).

I can understand the answer but I am not sure how to approach this problem if Cc << C is not given. So I what I am asking is what would be general strategy to solve such problems.

Comment: A LC circuit is a tank oscillator circuit, which will oscillate, as B has a extra capacitance ,it has more charge holding capacity than the A.

Answer (score 3):

You could make an extreme case examination. If Cc is a lot smaller than C you could argue that Cc (as an example) *could* be zero and, in this extreme case, circuit (B) will continue to resonate until the end of time.

Another way of looking at it is by examing the AC voltage across the resistor in (B) - it can only ever be lower in amplitude compared to voltage across the resistor in circuit (A) therefore, the circuit losses in (B) have to be lower and therefore circuit (B) takes longer to decay.

Now what if Cc were infinite? This would turn circuit (B) into circuit (A) therefore, by inspection, for any reasonable value of Cc, the voltage across R will be less than it would be when Cc is infinite. There is only one conclusion here and that is this: circuit (B) takes longer to decay than circuit (A).

Comment: Thanks a lot this helps but could you tell me how this can be solved in general.

Comment: You could use a simulator or you could derive the mathematical formula for the decaying waveform. However, it makes no difference because, no matter how big or small Cc is, by inspection, the voltage across R has to be smaller in (B) than in (A) therefore, observations tells me that (B) will decay for a longer time than (A).